# Does tesseract OCR library works on windows 7 64 bit systems?

Tags: android, windows-7, ocr, tesseract

I want to get one thing cleared that is it true that the tesseract the most appropriate library for ocr is not compatible for windows 7 64 bit computers. I am working on one such android application and have a 64 bit system, its actually not running on it and giving me some "unsatisfied link error" in debug view. I searched over web some view were like it works well and others were its not possible yet. Please help to get out of this problem.
If its not possible to run this library with window 7 64 bit then what steps i need to take to make it run.
Would be great full for any kind of guidance provided.

Answer (score 1):

I can say that I build weeks ago my own Android app with Tesseract on Windows 7 64 bits. And I didn´t find any compatibility problems, neither I read any problems related with that.

Here it is the guide that I followed. Hope it helps.
-> http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Comment: ok. Then please can you help me to find the real issue behind the problem i am facing to run it? There is no problem in importing library in eclipse and then in project, but when i debug the code for text reading it gives me "unsatisfied link error" in debug view and class file editor window opens and it says that "sdk/platforms/android-15/ android.jar has no source attachment". I have recently installed eclipse juno and made it sure to download all resources for android-15 that  i am using for my application.